# How can I put local Moodle installation under version control

Tags: moodle

I have setup local installation of Moodle and i have created some courses there and did some customization. Now i want to

1.) put this under version control on an existing bitbucket project and

2.) deploy it to  server.

can someone please advise how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The code is already under version control - just pull it down using git (see https://docs.moodle.org/en/Git_for_Administrators for more details).

If, however, you are asking about how to transfer the configuration data from one site to the other - you can do that by exporting your database and importing it to the remote site (the instructions for doing this will vary depending on the database software you are using), as well as copying your moodledata directory. This assumes you are fine to completely replace the remote site with the data from your local site.

If you just want to transfer courses, then backup each course and restore them one at a time to the live site.

Comment: is this possible to customize moodle installation and upload to existing Bitbucket project

Comment: If you are referring to customising the Moodle code, then it is certainly possible to modify the code and push it to a bitbucket repo (I do this multiple times a day). However, if you want to install Moodle + configure the site settings / create courses, then they are stored in the database not in the code. You cannot sync the database via bitbucket.

Comment: Can you please help me with commiting code to bitbucket, and is there any way to sync database also

Comment: There are a lot of git tutorials out there - read through some of them and then come back here to ask specific questions. I've already addressed the issue of syncing databases - export the database (e.g. mysqldump) then import to the remote server (but this will delete the remote server database - it will not retain any existing data).

Comment: I have an existing repository on Bitbucket and  a local customized Moodle setup which is under version control of git , how can i commit the code to bitbucket